# jQuery slideToggle positioning

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a jQuery toggle menu using `.slideToggle()` function ( see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/u3EJT/) ). However, I would like to make the grey button to follow the sliding menu, i.e. to move the grey button to move on top of the sliding menu. What changes can I make ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="categories">
    <ul>
        <li>Category 1</li>
        <li>Category 2</li>
        <li>Category 3</li>
        <li>Category 4</li>
        <li>Category 5</li>
        <li>Category 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">Navigation pane</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function() {
        $('#categories').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#menu_service_nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#categories {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    left: 0;
}
#categories ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#categories ul li {
    margin-left: -30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat hacky way to do it.  I haven't figured out of there is a better way just yet.

It basically just duplicates the menu header inside the slide up list.  It hides the original on slide up and shows it again on slide down.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u3EJT/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="categories">
    <div class="menu">Navigation pane</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Category 1</li>
        <li>Category 2</li>
        <li>Category 3</li>
        <li>Category 4</li>
        <li>Category 5</li>
        <li>Category 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu">Navigation pane</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function() {
        $('#categories').slideToggle('fast');
        $('#menu').hide();
    });

    $('.menu').click(function() {
        $('#categories').slideToggle('fast', function() {
            $('#menu').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. this looks promising, but I'm still looking for a cleaner way (no need to duplicate the element). Let me try more.